Using Microsoft Graph for Teams from antother app
Here is the task:
When i have a specific ticket created in Jira i need to post a message to the MS Teams channel, but also to update it (i want to use Status field right in the message card) for each ticket status change. Best option is just to update the card but even reply in the created message thread also fine. That's why i can't use webhooks for the task.
Microsoft Graph provides all methods i need, like
POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/messages

or
PATCH /teams/(team-id)/channels/{channel-id}/messages/{message-id}

but the problem is with authentication. I'm aware of Delegated and Application identity but Delegated i don't know how to use in Jira (because it should be automated and user independent) and Application auth is looks like very limited because MS positioning it for migration purposes only.
I tried to use Application auth with the rights "Teamwork.Migrate.All" but i've got the error:
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.",

Delegated auth i have no idea how i can use for the automated app which should't be depended on any user, it must work automatically. Even just to pretend that i have service user account which i can use for this task i must consent on this account behalf to allow the app to use this acccount and then get and refresh token. Doesn't looks as a stable solution.
Any suggestions what is the solution for automated user-independent messaging + replying/updating for Teams?
